# Low refresh rate on 4K monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card

I have recently bought an ASUS PA328Q 3840x2160 monitor, which I'm using together with a smaller ASUS monitor. I'm using a Windows 10 PC with an nVidia GeForce GTX 780 (3,0GB DDR5 RAM).

When viewing a video on it, the refresh rate seems okay (not sure how I can measure it objectively).

However, when I'm working in a standard application like Microsoft Excel, an editor like Notepad++, or in Visual Studio, I notice something that feels like a refresh rate lag. The mouse cursor always seems to be a bit behind. It feels like working on a remote workstation through some kind of VPN solution (like Remote Desktop or TeamViewer), where it takes a fraction of a second for the mouse cursor to move. You move the mouse, and the mouse cursor follows a little bit later.

Here's something to demonstrate the problem. If I move the mouse in a fast circle, then on my old monitor it looks like this:

[image]

However, on the 4K monitor, it more looks like this:

[image]

This is the reason I'm suspecting a refresh rate problem. The rate at which the mouse cursor position is updated is way lower than on the old monitor.

Now, I have absolutely no idea where to go look for the problem. Could it be a problem with the graphics card? With the monitor? With the configuration?

How can I tell where's the problem?

Comment: How did you connect the display? If you're seeing your mouse in multiple places that would be the mouse "shadow" (or whatever it's called) setting in windows. You could objectively measure it by just displaying it (usually through the display OSD). In addition you could check the FPS using some program. Did you install the correct drivers and is it running at native resolution?

Comment: @Seth There are no drivers to install, and yes, it's showing 60 Hz refresh rate in the menu.

Comment: There still could be. Is it recognized as an Asus display? If it's showing 60 Hz it should be running with 60 Hz if you look at [this Tom's Hardware article](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/asus-pa328q-32-inch-ultra-hd-monitor,4356-7.html) it would put the display at ~65ms input lag. As such I'd look into either NVIDIA or System settings. Are you using pointer trails? What is your mouse speed set to? Don't forget that if you go for the same dimension of circle there are probably more PPI on your new display. Do you have that lag while windows are moving or e.g. a presentation is running?

Comment: @Seth Thank you! The ASUS webpage with the driver downloads didn't list any driver for Windows 10. After I installed the Windows 8 drivers, the lag was gone.

Comment: @cheesus Please post your comment as an answer and accept it as the answer to the question.  Thanks!

Comment: @cheeesus Please update your question to include the exact make and model of your graphics card as well as the connection type for *both* monitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you can't find any specific driver there still is a driver needed for a display. If you don't have one your display might be run as a generic display which could impact the performance. I'm not sure how much that driver is responsible for the utilization of things like overdrive or similar but at least it's involved with color. So check whenever the display shows up as an ASUS display or a generic one. If you look at the [support page](http://www.asus.com/Commercial-Monitors/PA328Q/HelpDesk_Download/) there seems to be driver available for Windows 7 and Windows 8.

If the OSD does show 60 Hz I'd go ahead and assume that it's running at 60 Hz. By looking at [this Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/asus-pa328q-32-inch-ultra-hd-monitor,4356-7.html) article it would put your display at around ~65 ms input lag which should be hardly noticeable in the manner you described.

Assuming it's not a faulty display (which is unlikely if it's showing this behavior) you would need to look into other software settings. If you're doing the same "size" of circle (physically) might be moving more pixels as the PPI of that display is probably higher. It's still not clear if you're using mouse pointer trials and you might be able to find some settings in the NVIDIA driver as well.